# Is there a way to filter out a frequency?

Tags: python, argmax

np.argmax function returns the highest frequency value and I want to take that value out and then see what the second highest value is.

```
import wave
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

There is some code here but that just defines the data of the sound wave and has nothing to do with my question.

```
data_fft = np.fft.fft(data)
frequencies = np.abs(data_fft)
print("The frequency is {} Hz".format(np.argmax(frequencies)))
frequency1 = frequencies - np.argmax(frequencies)
print(np.argmax(frequency1))
```

I can not figure out how to remove the highest frequency value. The code I showed returns 4561 as the highest value in frequencies and then I try to subtract that out in the new variable frequency1. When I print out the np.argmax of that I still get 4561. Does anyone know how I can remove this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.argmax()` gives you the *indices* of the maximum values along some axis, see [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

You subtract the indices from the values with:

```
frequency1 = frequencies - np.argmax(frequencies)
```

Instead, you wanted to remove the values at these indices, and the obtain the maximum value in the remaining data:

```
import numpy as np

data_fft = np.random.random(100)  # I don't have your data, so generating some
frequencies = np.abs(data_fft)
print("The highest frequency is at position {}".format(np.argmax(frequencies)))
new_frequencies = np.delete(frequencies, np.argmax(frequencies))
print("The 2nd highest frequency is at position {}".format(np.argmax(new_frequencies)))
print("And its value is {}".format(np.max(new_frequencies)))
```

Although it's a matter of style,  the default string delimiter for Python is a single quote `'` and you may find f-strings more readable:

```
import numpy as np

data_fft = np.random.random(100)
frequencies = np.abs(data_fft)

print(f'The highest frequency is at position {np.argmax(frequencies)}')
new_frequencies = np.delete(frequencies, np.argmax(frequencies))

print(f'The 2nd highest frequency is at position {np.argmax(new_frequencies)}')
print(f'And its value is {np.max(new_frequencies)}')
```